# How to remove JavaScript array element and reset keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below:

```
 var fields = [
    {name:"mark", age:"23"}, 
    {name:"smith", age:"28"}, 
    {name:"kelvin", age:"25"}, 
    {name:"micheal", age:"22"}
];
```

I understand that fields will now have index/keys 0,1,2,3

How do I delete index 2 and reset keys so that we now have 0,1,2 instead of 0,1,3

Comment: That's actually just a normal array, with objects.

Comment: array.splice(2,1);

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly you want to remove array element at index 2 and re-index the array so there is no empty space. If that's the case javascript has got you covered.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```
fields.splice(2,1); // This modifies your original array and removes only one element starting at index 2.
```

Comment: Just a heads up, I meant to upvote, tag me if an edit is made and I'll reverse the downvote