# How to remove all item from json and get empty object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am using jquery to manage dynamic list of objects.

```
var data = [];
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
    data.push({name: myname, address: myadress});
}
```

// now when I try to delete item from data object, when there is only one object in data, jquery retruns [empty]

```
console.log(data); //get  [empty], data with length = 1
```

[image]

so this breaks my control, which helps me to leave submit button disabled.
how can I deal with it?

Comment: `empty` isn't a keyword in JS so I can't see how you get `[empty]` as an output. Could you show a more complete example of how you remove the items from the array

Comment: You can check image in my post

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That's the console output after you `delete` items from an array as, although you removed the content, the array length is unaffected. See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements) for more info. As for a fix, I'd suggest creating the array at the point it's needed instead of trying to `push()`/`delete` items from it at runtime

Comment: Ok for your suggestion, but I need to let users enter a lot of information. so I return an object with all items they entered, and I send to server on submit. I do not know how I can do it with another way. So when I check my data length before activating my submit button I see 1. There is something in the array, I think, if not why I am getting 1 as length?

Comment: How to get 0 ? this will fix my issue. the data I am getting creates bug serverside.

Comment: `There is something in the array, I think, if not why I am getting 1 as length?` because the array bounds have been set, but there is no longer any actual content within the array. If you want to remove and re-index the array, use `splice()` instead of delete, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296248/how-to-remove-javascript-array-element-and-reset-keys/38296299)

Comment: Thank youuuuuu :)